# How to get progress information or time remaining from sklearn.mixture.GMM

Tags: scipy, scikit-learn

I am running gaussian mixture models (sklearn.mixure.GMM) on a fairly large data set.
The class get a parameter called n_iter which is the number of iteration of expectation-maximization iterations to run.

I want to get some sense of how much time is remaining or how much iterations the algorithm has already done.
I know some other sklearn functions have verbosity parameters but this one doesn't.
What is the best approach? I would rather not change the source code because this should run on other computers as well.

Comment: You can upgrade to the current dev version, where GMM does have a verbose setting: http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GMM.html#sklearn.mixture.GMM

Comment: thank you @andreas. I will just wait for the next version then (for future readers, in version 0.17, the GMM function should have a verbose parameter that you should set)

Comment: You can also install the development version, it should be reasonable stable, but might give you some weird deprecation warnings currently.